# gulp-sassでコンパイルすると@includeが使えず「no mixin named 」エラーが出る

Tags: gulp, sass

gulp-sassを使ってscssファイルをコンパイルしようとするとエラーが出ます
（手打ちなのでスペース数は違うかもしれませんが）

```
 Error: src\sass\style.scss
Error: no mixin named test
    Backtrace:
     stdin:エラー行
     on line エラー行 of stdin
>>  @include test;
```

エラー行は@includeしている行です。
gulpfile.jsのコンパイル部分は以下のようになっています。
実際はgulp-plumberを使っていますが、抜いても入れてても変わりませんでした。

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');



gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('./src/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});
```

@mixinを書くことは問題ないのですが、@includeを使うとエラーがでます。

Answer (score 1):

@includeの後に@mixinを書いていました、コードは絶対あっていると思っていました…
お騒がせしました。